# Variable Choices based on ARGV

Tags: perl, variables, argv

I have an input ARGV value from a bash script that is either (yes) or (no).
I need (yes) or (no) to equal a numerical value (1) or (0) and the output
based on that ARGV value to be the numerical value.

My attempt is getting something like this to work:  script.pl yes &

```
my $VAR1=         $ARGV[0];
my $yes=1;
my $no=0;
print $VAR1;
```

Output of the print is: 1 (not the word yes)

Sorry my example seems obviously silly because $VAR1 is obviously whatever I used as the ARG value. So what I'm looking to do is take an ARGV and check it against a list of preset values and then output the value of that preset.

Thanks,

** I'm a perl noob. My apology if I'm not explaining this correctly.

Comment: You could try use a hash, for example: `perl -E '%input_map = ( yes => 1, no => 0 ); say $input_map{ +shift }' yes`

Comment: The perl -E is running it from the command line. How can I write this in my script as an ARGV?  The variable is being passed from another script and I'm doing something a tad more complex that just yes or no in the perl script. I'm just using this as an example for security reasons.  If I know how to take an ARGV value and check it against a list of preset values, so the output is the preset value, then I'm good to go from there.

Comment: Hi Alby. The `shift` in my example is a shortcut for `shift @ARGV`

Comment: Can somebody please vote up my question? I have received -2 and that has hurt my ability to post future questions. I have no idea what I've done wrong or how to correct it.

Comment: Hi Alby. I am not sure what more information you need to solve your problem. But feel free to contact me by email for further assistance :)

Comment: @Alby, People are just tired of telling people [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) "every single day".

Answer (score 3):

So you want to look up one value based on another. To do that, a hash is usually the tool to use.

```
my %yes_no_to_bool = (
   yes => 1,
   no  => 0,
);

@ARGV == 1
   or die("usage\n");

my ($arg) = @ARGV;

exists($yes_no_to_bool{$arg})
   or die("usage\n");

my $bool = $yes_no_to_bool{$arg};
```